# Rails route issue after upgrading to rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

After upgrading to Rails 6.1, I'm getting following error:

```
undefined method `find_script_name' for nil:NilClass
```

In this case the route is being used is `root_path` but getting this for many other routes too! `routes.rb` is as following (tried like this after removing all other route definitions)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Only relevant thing I found online is [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8cbcd19d7079db1b5df6ddb3b813fea57cd5cc38). Anyone has idea what could be wrong?

I'm running on ruby `2.7.2`

Comment: Where is the method `find_script_name` located?  Is it in the `application_controller.rb` or something?  Have you recently also added any new gems or anything?

Comment: it's in rails core (actionpack) as I linked in original post! i am seeing this after trying to upgrade to rails 6.1!

Comment: @HungryCoder just ran into the same problem. Did you find a solution? Seems to be somehow related to path helpers used in views.

Comment: I have switched back to `6.0.4.1`  and I got rid of this problem and a few other problems

Answer (score 3):

it looks like a bug in the current release of rails 6.1

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42218

the current fix is to prefix all path helper calls inside the views with:

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.`

so **session_path** becomes **Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.session_path**