# Included route helper not working after upgrade to Rails 6.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code used to work in Rails 6.0.4.8 but no longer works in 6.1.X (I tried all minor versions, even the latest 6.1.6 has this behaviour; the engine itself is legacy code, unfortunately, we can't remove it easily):

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.named_routes.url_helpers_module.include(DynUrlHelper)

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: "/"
end
```

```rb
# app/helpers/dyn_url_helper.rb
module DynUrlHelper
  def dyn_path(target)
    # ...
  end
end
```

It throws an undefined method error when I try to use `#dyn_path` in a controller or view:

```
undefined method `dyn_path' for #<MyController:0x00007facc9227298>
```

Upon investigating the issue, I noticed, that **when I change a file and Zeitwerk reloads my code, it works!** But a fresh started app fails. So I guess it has something to do with caching the named routes helpers?

The only thing I found is this question [Rails route issue after upgrading to rails 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383035/rails-route-issue-after-upgrading-to-rails-6-1) linking to this Github issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42218. But I'm not sure if it really is the same problem.